Curved hallways
I am searching for a way, how to make hallways smoothly curved as on included screenshot. Or can someone recommend me the tools/modifiers I have to use and the process?
Adjusted screenshot so that you can see the details without having to be in a dark room:

Original screenshot:


Or can someone recommend me the tools/modifiers I have to use and the process.

What have you tried as far? What are you struggling with as far? Can you form a more specific question? Right now you are pretty much asking to be taught modelling and texturing. It's too much for a single answer. You should form a specific question in the title as well.

For a one-off, or arbitrary hand-built connections, Bridge Edge Loops would seem a reasonable tool for this:

... here seen linking simple extrusions of a profile made from a plane with its upper vertices CtrlShift
B bevelled.
